# How to fetch fields from Contact, opportunity, case for a particular Account

Tags: apex

I am pretty new to Salesforce and started working on it, I came across a requirement where I need to fetch few fields from Contact, Case, Opportunity for a particular account to show them on LWC form.

After researching I came to know that it can be achieved through Wrapper class.

Can anyone help me out in writing wrapper class for the same please if possible.

```
public class AccountContactController{
  
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<AccountContactListWrapper> getAllAccountWithContacts(){
    List<AccountContactListWrapper> accWrapperList = new List<AccountContactListWrapper>();
    List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingState, Website, Phone,
                                (SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Name, Email From Contacts)
                                FROM Account WHERE Name LIMIT 5];
    if(!accList.isEmpty()){
        for(Account acc : accList){
            AccountContactListWrapper accWrapper = new AccountContactListWrapper();
            accWrapper.accRecord = acc;
            accWrapper.contactList = acc.Contacts;
            accWrapper.contactCount = acc.Contacts.size();
            accWrapperList.add(accWrapper);
        }
    }
    return accWrapperList;
}
  
// wrapper class with @AuraEnabled and {get;set;} properties 
public class AccountContactListWrapper{
    @AuraEnabled
    public Account accRecord{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<Contact> contactList{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public Integer contactCount{get;set;}
}
```

}

Comment: This is not a code provider service portal, please try yourself first and if you face an issue then post your specific question with issue or error you are facing.

Comment: @NagendraSinghI posted the code I have tried but not sure how to pass the particular accountId to it

Comment: What do you mean "pass the particular accountId to it"? Where is the account ID of interest? Is the LWC intended to be used in an Account record page? If so, add `@api recordId` to your LWC and pass this as a reactive variable parameter to the wire call to the `get*` Apex method. See [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about), specifically the section called "Mark a Configuration Object Property as Dynamic and Reactive".